# Is the ASUS Strix GTX 970 completely incompatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, 14.10

I've been running Ubuntu for a long tim (since 6.something) and I'm completely stuck on this one. Until recently I was running a geforce 670, dual-booting Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 8.1 with no issues. I upgraded to the Geforce 970, which Windows picked up and worked with immediately, but Ubuntu seems to refuse to talk to. It just boots to a black screen and that's it. So far I've tried...

- Purging and reinstalling the nvidia drivers
- Switching to the lastest edgers drivers from their PPA
- Running in graphics failsafe mode
- Running the Ubuntu 14.10 live CD
- Running the Ubuntu 14.10 live USB
- Running the Linux Mint 17.1 live CD
- Unplugging all extra monitors so it only boots with a single screen connected

...and nothing has made any difference. Even graphics failsafe and the live CDs just boot to a blank screen. At this point I'm completely out of ideas. If Windows had been having issues too I'd suspect the card was faulty, but it's been running flawlessly for a week now. And if it was a driver issue then I'd assume the live cd/graphics failsafe/live cd from another distro would have had some different effect. If anybody has any ideas or suggestions, I'd be very grateful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my MSI Gtx 970 for a while now that I can't figure out. The card outputs to one of my monitors, but not another on the default driver. A TTY (by pressing ctrl+atl+F1) remains a blank black unusable screen.
I tried using all the different install methods to install the proprietary drivers here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/nvidia-343-22-install-in-ubuntu-1404/ but it all results in me ruining my install.
I even tried updating my kernel before installing the nvidia proprietary drivers.
Ubuntu doesn't say there are proprietary drivers in the additional drivers gui.

I'm really upset about it, it's totally unusable and I can't fix it.